# NextJS tRPC Typescript errors: Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type 'void' / Type X is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, next.js, trpc.io

I had typescript strict mode set to true and these errors weren't coming up in VS Code but when I went to deploy to Vercel it picked them up and the build failed. I then turned strict mode off and these errors showed up in a number of locations in VS Code.

I'm new to typescript, so I'm well over my head here, and not sure how I can type these void and undefined items so the error is resolved.  I've spent 5 hrs crawling over the internet, probably with incorrect search terms, unable to find how to solve this.

below has an example of both issues:

```
// admin.tsx

import { trpc } from "../../utils/trpc";

function Admin(props: {id: number}) {

  // fetch data with id results in error:
  // Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

  const { data: countdown, isLoading } = trpc.useQuery([
    "countdown.getCountdownAdmin",
    {
      id: props.id,
    },
  ]);

  
  // below relates to the parameter of type void error

  const utils = trpc.useContext();
  const mutateResults = trpc.useMutation(["countdown.updateResults"], {
    async onSuccess() {
      await utils.invalidateQueries(["countdown.getCountdownAdmin"]);
    },
  });

  // the error presents on this function.  Error message:
  // Argument of type '{ countdownId: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.

  async function generateResults() {
    const data = await mutateResults.mutateAsync({
      countdownId: countdown.id,
    });
  }
return (
{some unimportant stuff here}
  );
}

export default Admin;
```

On the server side (I've removed unrelated queries):

```
// countdown.ts

import { TRPCError } from "@trpc/server";
import { createProtectedRouter } from "./protected-router";
import { z } from "Zod";

export const countdownProtected = createProtectedRouter()
.query("getCountdownAdmin", {
    input: z.object({
      id: z.number(),
    }),
    async resolve({ ctx, input }) {
      const { id } = input;
      try {
        const countdown = await ctx.prisma.countdowns.findUnique({
          where: {
            id: id,
          },
          include: {
            UserCountdowns: {
              include: {
                User: {
                  include: {
                    Votes: {
                      where: {
                        countdownId: id,
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            Results: true,
            InviteCode: true,
          },
        });

        return countdown;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw new TRPCError({
          code: "BAD_REQUEST",
        });
      }
    },
  })
.mutation("updateResults", {
    input: z.object({
      countdownId: z.number(),
    }),
    async resolve({ ctx, input }) {
      const { countdownId } = input;
      // const user = ctx.session?.user?.id;

      try {
        const data = await ctx.prisma.countdowns.findUnique({
          where: {
            id: countdownId,
          },
          include: {
            Votes: {
              include: {
                User: true,
              },
              orderBy: {
                id: "asc",
              },
            },
          },
        });

        // long and unrelated function here that I've cut out
        
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw new TRPCError({
          code: "BAD_REQUEST",
        });
      }
    },
  });
```

Comment: Can you show us the full error stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can as I'm having trouble running the debug mode.  Without removing all authentication verification from my frontend and backend code I can't access it as Chrome won't allow me to authenticate with Google to access the site.  Something to do with it being automated by VS Code?

Thank you for your reply though.  Not ideal but I'm using @ts-check to allow the site to build on Vercel and removing it while making changes, just ignoring these errors that I can't explain.